# Как установить вид гибрид для карты

Tags: python, yandex-static-maps-api

```
def get_response(coords, map_scale, mode, point_coords):
    server = "http://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/"
    params = {
        "ll": coords,
        "spn": map_scale,
        "l": mode,
        "size": "650,400"
    }

    if point_coords:
        params["pt"] = f"{point_coords},pm2lbm"

    response = requests.get(server, params=params)

    if not response:
        return False, response

    return True, response
```

В `mode` приходит `sat%2Cskl` для вида Гибрид, но почему-то возвращает ошибку. При этом при передаче `map` или `sat` все работает нормально